# Terraform init fails on WSL

Tags: docker, terraform, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the below code :

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source = "kreuzwerker/docker"
    }
  }
}
```

when I run `terraform init`, it fails on my WSL Ubuntu with this error :

```
Error: Failed to install provider
│ 
│ Error while installing kreuzwerker/docker v2.20.0: could not query provider registry for registry.terraform.io/kreuzwerker/docker: failed to retrieve
│ authentication checksums for provider: the request failed after 2 attempts, please try again later: Get
│ "https://github.com/kreuzwerker/terraform-provider-docker/releases/download/v2.20.0/terraform-provider-docker_2.20.0_SHA256SUMS": net/http: request canceled while
│ waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Why is it timing out ? What can I do here?

Comment: If you insist on running Terraform in WSL, you are in for a world of pain. I would run it from windows.

Comment: @TheFool It runs fine for me on WSL2. Just like running in a stand-alone install of Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have network access inside your WSL? Can you `curl` that URL it is trying to hit?

Comment: @MarkB, I get frequent issues, mostly regardnling the non compliant nameserver of wls2 and the fact that tf is written on go and go is super strict about it.  There is a number of issues in GH for this, i.e. https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8022.